# Raspbian Jessie network configurations doubts

Tags: pi-3, networking, raspbian-jessie, ethernet

I have installed the latest Jessie version 2017-08-16 on my Rpi3. I am confused about the network configuration. Jessie shipped with dhcpcd5 and isc-dhcp-client, right?
Whether this meaning that, jessie has built-in dhcp server in it?

Or if we want to configure dhcp server on Rpi, do we need to install dnsmasq or something like that?

Now I am in a project in which Rpi has to be configured as an ethernet router (from eth0 to eth1). I  have tried this in old version of raspbian and it worked. I have used dnsmasq for congiuring dhcp server and used /etc/network/interfaces for static ip configuration.

When I come to Jessie, I am confused whether it is required to use dnsmasq. I already understand how to configure static IP addresses in Jessie. But the problem is with dhcp server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=132674) has some good info for the pi3. As you said that already done some steps, here it's a short version:

It says that you need to install dnsmasq with:

```
sudo apt-get install rpi-update dnsmasq -y
```

You said that already have wifi and a static ip setup, so, moving on those steps, into dnsmasq config.

First, save the old file and create a new one:

```
sudo mv /etc/dnsmasq.conf /etc/dnsmasq.conf.orig  
sudo nano /etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

and add:

```
interface=eth0      # Use interface eth0  
listen-address=172.24.1.1 # Explicitly specify the address to listen on  
bind-interfaces      # Bind to the interface to make sure we aren't sending things elsewhere  
server=8.8.8.8       # Forward DNS requests to Google DNS  
domain-needed        # Don't forward short names  
bogus-priv           # Never forward addresses in the non-routed address spaces.  
dhcp-range=172.24.1.50,172.24.1.150,12h # Assign IP addresses between 172.24.1.50 and 172.24.1.150 with a 12 hour lease time
```

Enable IPv4 forwarding:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Uncomment the following line:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

IP Tables Add this:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Configure it to load on reboot by first saving it to a file:

```
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat"
```

Then create a 'hook' file with a line to restore the ip tables:

```
sudo nano /lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/70-ipv4-nat
```

Add:

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

After a reboot you should automatically connect to your wifi and, assuming it has internet access, anything plugged into your Pi's ethernet port will have internet access as well.

Comment: why we need this file sudo nano /lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/70-ipv4-nat, We can restore tables in /etc/network/interfaces file, right?

Comment: What about the dhcpcd in the Jessie?

Comment: i followed https://mylinuxcode.com/how-to-make-static-ip-on-raspberry-pi/ tutorial for setting static IP. I think it have to work

Comment: Cool! If it was helpful, please remember to mark as right. :)

Comment: Can you help me for setting static IP. The tutorial doesn't work for me

Comment: @vishnumc make sure that you're changing the values regarding your network parameters